# Is it possible to use Nautilus Actions with Nemo file manager?

Tags: filemanager, nemo, nautilus-actions

I have installed Nemo (initially a Nautilus fork) in Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS.

I used to use Nautilus actions with Nautilus. Now that I have installed Nemo, I can't use them anymore.

I was wondering if there is any way to use Nautilus actions and [the Configuration tool](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/nautilus-actions/) with Nemo - as it is a fork of Nautilus.

---

- Can Nautilus actions be used in Nemo? How?
- Is the Nautilus actions tool (editor) usable for Nemo?

Comment: Are you still looking for an answer to this? Nemo is now in the Ubuntu repositories, but it might be a better idea for someone to ask a new question (instead of reopening this) if you don't really care anymore. So are you still interested in seeing this answered and addressed?

Comment: @Seth - I am interested in an answer on this for 14.04. I am using Nemo as default file manager and Cinnamon as desktop. Should I create a new question? - And why was this closed? - I have edited it to fresh it up a bit. Should I try to open it? Or is this better fitted on Unix&Linux?

Comment: @cipricus the only question I have: we have to answer problems with forks? Back in 2012 Nemo was not an official product. If it is now part of an --official release-- I would ask a new question otherwise it would be better suited on U&L or on a forum dedicated to Nemo (going straight for the maintainer is mosttimes the best option).

Comment: @Rinzwind - fork or not it is a third-party application running on Ubuntu (meaning ubuntu os, not the desktop). I see that this is largely within [the scope defined by the community (Questions that you may ask)](http://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic). - Also, this is possibly a 'yes or no' question, I do not see why an answer should not be given to that, especially that I expect it to be 'no'.

Comment: Go ahead and ask a new question @cipricus. I'm not really sure why this was closed in the first place as it is software running on Ubuntu. No one might have an answer, but I see no reason you can't ask about it.

Comment: @cipricus fine but your audience will be small and a good answer might be difficult. I for one will not install Nemo just to test if it is possible ;)

Comment: @Rinzwind - some people think ubuntu=unity=nautilus; but not only there are xubuntu-xfce-thunar and lubuntu-lxde-pcmanfm etc, but some people also use any of the initial *ubuntu installation with other DE (Mate, Cinnamon, Gnome, Enlightenment) and file managers (Nemo, Dolphin etc). Nemo seems increasingly popular and people who use it have usually used Nautilus in the past (and its 'actions' and actions-tool etc), so, this seems a good and interesting question.

Comment: @Seth - I have [already asked it on U&L](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/170061/32012). Here I vote to reopen and if reopened I will put a bounty and I will edit it to update to 14.04

Comment: @cipricus That question is now open.

Answer (score 2):

Found this on the Arch wiki -

[image]

`.nemo_action` files can be used to create menu entries in the pop-up dialog that comes up since these files are read by nemo whenever you right click. You can invoke a script from these `.nemo_action` files that does your job, similar to what `nautilus-actions` does.

You can have a look at `/usr/share/nemo/actions/sample.nemo_action` and `/usr/share/nemo/actions/myaction.py` to get an idea of how it works. These files have detailed information on what each field in the action files indicates.

You can visit [this website](http://manikandanc.wordpress.com/2014/07/16/nemo-actions-comparing-single-file/) for an example.

**Edit :**

Nemo actions are similar to nautilus actions in content but vary with respect to the extension name.

In nautilus, newly created actions and menus will be stored on the disk as `.desktop` files.

The `nautilus-actions` tool, a graphical editor for nautilus actions, will therefore not work with nemo because it looks for `.desktop` files, not `.nemo_action` files.

Summary -

Nautilus scripts can be used if invoked by `.nemo_action` files, just like nautilus action `.desktop` files did, and these in turn can be adapted for that purpose. `nautilus-actions` tool is NOT usable for Nemo due to the difference in paths and extension names.

Comment: so, we have similar actions, with files that have different names, as they are called `nemo_action`, but with the same content I presume. Please specify if so. Also the nautilus actions tool (editor for nautilus actions) should not work with nemo because it calls for `nautilus_action`, not `nemo_action`. Please add these details to the answer to make it definitive and grant bounty.

Comment: [Nemo Custom actions help Linux Mint](http://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=208&t=153517)

Comment: please consider edit to give clear answers to my two sub-questions

Comment: Edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: Made a correction. Nautilus actions are stored as `.desktop` files, not `.nautilus_action` files.

Comment: to get a nautilus action into nemo one should just copy/paste the content of a nautilus action file (.desktop) into a nemo action file?

Comment: Haven't tried it out but judging from the syntax, they are similar and hence it should work.

Comment: scripts and actions seem two different things aren' t they?

Comment: Yes. Actions are more like `.desktop` files and they are responsible for creating the menu entries. However, it is the script, which is invoked by the action, that does the actual job.

Comment: so the answer is: 1) nautilus scripts can be used if invoked by nemo_action files, just like nautilus actions did, and these can be adapted for that purpose; 2) Nautilus actions tool (editor) is NOT usable for Nemo

Comment: Yes. That is a concise way to sum it up.

Answer (score 1):

I use Nemo without Cinnamon on Ubuntu 14.04 using [a PPA](https://launchpad.net/~webupd8team/+archive/ubuntu/nemo).

Nemo is much more configurable then Nautilus. Whether or not that is "better" then Nautilus is a matter of taste IMHO.  I prefer complex things over simple ones… :-)

That being said, defining your personal Nemo actions or nemo scripts is very straightforward: scripts can be copied verbatim in 90+% of cases and actions can be defined yourself easily (I made my own "Add to VLC" and "Open with BackInTime" in 5 minutes flat by using the provided [example](https://github.com/linuxmint/nemo/blob/master/files/usr/share/nemo/actions/sample.nemo_action))  You can also find tons of user-designed actions around the web.

There are tons of [extensions](https://github.com/linuxmint/nemo-extensions) readily available, so the need to define your own actions is hardly needed…

Comment: i like your answer and so i will give you a bounty in a few hours

Answer (score 1):

Summing up what I have learned from the [main answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/554184/47206):

1. Nemo or Nautilus actions are similar in content  and purpose (namely, adding menu items) but vary with respect to the extension name. (In nautilus, newly created actions and menus will be stored on the disk as `.desktop` files, In nemo as `nemo_action` files.) They invoke certain commands including scripts (which are in this sense called nautilus or nemo scripts). Therefore, **nautilus scripts can be used if invoked by nemo_action files**, just like nautilus actions did, and **these can be adapted** for that purpose
2. **The `nautilus-actions` tool, a graphical editor for nautilus actions, will therefore not work with nemo** because it looks for `.desktop` files, not `.nemo_action` files.